# Is it possible to remap topics at runtime?

Tags: ros, roscore, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering if mappings are dynamic or handled centrally enough that it would be possible to remap a nodes topics at runtime without requiring specific support within the node.

I've seen a post on the old mailing list that suggested it was not supported, but I'm wondering more specifically if it's even feasible if one's inclined to dig below supplied tools.

Implicit question: how does remapping work under the hood?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31718/is-it-possible-to-remap-topics-at-runtime?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2012-04-12

Post score: 5

Comment: "how does remapping work under the hood?"  This was answered in https://answers.ros.org/question/308693/how-does-remap-work-internally/ (but because no upvotes and not getting marked as answered that didn't make it to robotics.stackexchange)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current implementation is not capable of dynamically remapping.  I don't think that there's anything technically blocking this capability, though it will take a bunch of effort to do the book keeping and subscribe and unsubscribe and everything in a thread safe manner.  Also there's not really an API designed for it, but it definitely sounds like it might be a good enhancement to consider for future releases.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using [mux](http://ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/mux) from the [topic tools](http://ros.org/wiki/topic_tools) package you should be able to do what you describe. It has one output topic (which would go into your node) and multiple input topics. You can then choose which one of those gets forwarded as output.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-04-12**:
Those would certainly work, but would add an unnecessary and potentially expensive layer. Hopefully they'll eventually be made into nodelets. But I'm more asking in a conceptual/architectural sense.